# Stated Preference and Socioeconomic Data

Tags: multinomial-logit

I am conducting a survey which includes a stated choice experiment and socioeconomic-related questions. In the stated preference experiment, each respondent faces 3 scenarios. And, I am trying to develop a multinomial logit model.

How can I combine the SP observations (which will be 3*N) with Socioeconomic data (N)?

Should I just merge them based on the respondent ID which will result in a dataset of 3*N records? The socioeconomic data will be repeated three times for each respondent.

Is this right?

Answer (score 0):

If they face three scenarios then each can be a separate variable and there is no need to have more than one observation per person.